# Use STDIN during docker build from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install Miniconda in a docker image as a first step, right now this is what I have:

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget
RUN wget *miniconda download URL* && bash file_downloaded.sh
```

When I try to build the image, it goes well until it starts popping the following message continously:
*>>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no'*
At that point I need to stop docker build. How can I fix it? Should I include something in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can pass `-b` flag to `miniconda` shell script to avoid manual answering

```
Installs Miniconda3 4.0.5

    -b           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
                 it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
    -f           no error if install prefix already exists
    -h           print this help message and exit
    -p PREFIX    install prefix, defaults to $PREFIX
```

something like that:

```
RUN wget http://......-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
RUN chmod +x miniconda.sh \
    && bash ./miniconda.sh -b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't attach interactive tty during image build. If it is asking for 'yes' or 'no' during package installation, `wget` in your case, you can replace the corresponding line with `RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y wget`. If it is `bash file_downloaded.sh`, check if `file_downloaded.sh` accepts 'yes' or 'no' as a command line argument.

If `file_downloaded.sh` doesn't have that option, create a container from  `ubuntu:14.04` image, install `wget` and run your commands manually there. Then, you can make an image of the container by committing your changes like: `docker commit <cotainer_id> <image_name>`.